# Objective-C: class as parameter

Tags: ios, objective-c

is it possible to create an object of a type class A, knowing that A was passed as a parameter.
Typically:

```
Class A=[MyClass class];
....
A * object=[[A alloc]...]; //incorrect code here !
```

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You can't use a variable as the type of a variable. You need to use `id`.

```
Class A = [MyClass Class];
....
id object = [[A alloc]...];
```

Comment: and how about if you then want to cast to this type A ? like (A*)B ?

Comment: `id` gets implicitly cast to any pointer type. Declaring the types of variables is largely for the compiler to do type checking; it can't do that if it doesn't know the type.

Comment: A isn't a type. A is an object of type Class. You can't write "int x; x y; " and expect y to have type int.

Answer (score 0):

A is a variable, in fact it is a reference to an object much like all the other objects.  You can't therefore use it where the compiler is expecting type.  You should declare `object` as an `id` or some other superclass of the types you know that A could be.  The following code works fine, for example.

```
-(void) testFooBar
{
    Class foo = [NSMutableString class];
    NSString* bar = [[foo alloc] initWithFormat: @"Message: %@", @"Hello, World"];
    NSLog(@"bar is %@, class name %@", bar, [bar className]);
}
```

And produces the following

```
2014-04-17 16:29:49.962 BigNumber[62212:303] bar is Message: Hello, World, class name __NSCFString
```